# Lcross Confidence Envelopes - R software

Tags: r, spatial, bivariate, point-process

I have performed an Lcross examination in R with the following code:

```
intEnv  <- envelope(detractors.ppp, fun = Lcross, i="Park", j="Property", nsim = 999, r = 0:350, simulate = expression(rlabel(detractors.ppp)), correction="border")

plot(intEnv$r, intEnv$obs - intEnv$r, xlab='h', ylab='Lcross (Parks-Property Crime) - h',
     type="l", col='purple', ylim=c(-500,500), xlim=c(0,350),
     main="Lhat(interaction) - h for Parks & Property Crime")
abline(h=0, lty = 3)
lines(intEnv$r, intEnv$theo - intEnv$r, lty=3)
lines(intEnv$r, intEnv$hi - intEnv$r, lty=2, col='red')
lines(intEnv$r, intEnv$lo - intEnv$r, lty=2, col='red')
legend("topleft", inset=0.02, c("Parks-Property Crime", "Independence", "0.05 Envelopes"), lty=c(1,3,3,2), col=c("purple", "black", "red"))
```

However, the upper and lower confidence envelopes do not bound the horizontal X-axis (see below). This does not seem right to me. Can anyone offer an explanation of what might be happening here, and if I have done something wrong?

[image: img]

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). So, can you please edit your post and adjust the formatting to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

Your red dashed lines gives the upper and lower bounds for the simulations under the "null model" of random labelling conditional on the point locations. Simulation envelopes under a null model is not the same as a confidence region! The envelope is the area where you expect `Lcross-r` to be if your null model of random labelling holds. The black line is the theoretical line for independent components. Finally the purple line is the observed summary statistic `Lcross-r` for your data.

You should be able to get a similar plot by simply using `plot.fv` from `spatstat`.